# iPhone Core plot: how to zoom in this following example?

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

[image]

I am not talking about just resize the image,

I want to zoom in the price, then people focus on that price.

I want to do a resize action, then data will reload the specify area of the chart.

Similar as this application:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chart-tool/id366727994?mt=8
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can zoom in by adjusting the plot ranges on the plot space. Reduce the length of the range to zoom in and increase it to zoom out. No need to reload the data unless you want to add more detail (== more data points) at the higher zoom level.

Comment: Do you have a example for this? Because

Comment: Because i don't understand how to detect user use finger to do a Enlarge Action and change the plot range of the plot space....thank you

Comment: Pinch-zoom is handled automatically and should be enabled by default. Set `allowsUserInteraction = YES;` on your plot space to allow the user to scroll the plots by touching the plot space and dragging with their finger.